# Add data-attribute and its value to link with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript snippet that goes:

```
function(){
   location.href = '<%= my_route %>';
}
```

It turns this into the html

```
<a href="myroute">a certain text i have no problem here</a>
```

I would like to add with javascript data-no-turbolink = true to the link so that i have in html

```
<a href="myroute"  data-no-turbolink = true >a certain text i have no problem here</a>
```

I tried

```
function(){
   location.href = '<%= my_route %>' location.data-no-turbolink = true;
}
```

but it does not work.

How to do this ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you're using rails...?

Comment: Why not use: `:link_to`?

Comment: If you want pure javascript what's with the [tag:jquery] tag?

Comment: the link is not in the standard rails view but is inside a javascript modal: action: function(){
                              location.href = '<%= route_path %>';
                            } , as I'm using hubspot messenger: http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/

Comment: Figure out how to get the anchor, then figure out how to set an attribute, or search MDN for `dataset`, and you should be set.

Comment: Well keep in my `location` is a `window` property and not a recognized as an anchor tag that can have attributes assigned to it. Are you sure `location` is what you want to use?

Comment: yes only way I could make my thing work with hubspot messenger (.http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/) and some of my app specificities..

Comment: Take a look and see if my answer addresses your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location.setAttribute('data-no-turbolink', true)
```

should do the trick. [Dom API setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: is setAttribute working for IE<=8. If not is there a shim or polyfill or sth to make it work at least on IE8?

Comment: I don't understand how this works without throwing an error: `Uncaught TypeError: window.location.setAttribute is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this via Javascript and assuming that there's an anchor element present on the page:

```
<%= link_to "Example Link", example_path, { class: "example-link" } %>
```

---

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var exampleLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("example-link");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(exampleLinks, function(elem, index) {
      elem.setAttribute("data-no-turbolink", "true");
  });
});
```

Though you can easily do this right in your rails template:

```
<%= link_to "Example Link", example_path, { data: { "data-no-turbolink": true } } %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i think it should work but the problem is I can't use inside the .js the Rails route and prefered to go the easy way (vs using sth like js-routes) by using gon and using location.href = ....inside hubspot messenger 'action urls' location.href = action: function(){
                              location.href = '<%= actual_deal_page_path(@deal) %>';

Comment: but I'll upvote as it could be useful to other people with different constraint than I have. thanks a lot for the help